# Scala HashMap throwing key not found exception

Tags: java, scala, iterator, hashmap, key

I am very new to Scala, and would appreciate any help (have looked everywhere and spent the last 8 hours trying to figure this out)

Currently I have

```
def apply(file: String) : Iterator[String] =  {
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().map(_.toLowerCase)
    }
```

As well as

```
def groupFreq[A,B](xs: Iterator[A], f: A => B): HashMap[B, Int] = { 
    var freqMap = new HashMap[B, Int]
    for (x <- xs) freqMap = freqMap + ( f(x) -> ( freqMap.getOrElse( f(x) , 0 ) +1 )  )  
    freqMap
  }
```

apply just takes a file of words that we pass in.

GroupFreq takes xs: Iterator[A] and a grouping function f that converts A values to their B groups.
The function returns a HashMap that for each B group, counts the number of A values that fell into the group.

I use both of these functions, to help me with charFreq, a function that uses both apply and groupFreq to pass back a HashMap that counts how many times a Char appears throughout the entire file. If the char does not appear anywhere in the file, then there should be no mapping for it.

```
def charFreq(file: String): HashMap[Char, Int] = 
  {
    var it = Iterator[Char]()
    val words = apply(file)
    for {
        xs<-words
    } yield { it = it ++ xs.toIterator }

    val chars   = it
    val grouper = (x: Char) => x
    groupFreq(chars, grouper) 
  }
```

My solution compiles and apply and groupFreq work as intended, but when I run charFreq, it says

> charFreq threw an exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not
>   found: d

I believe I'm doing something wrong, most likely with my for loop and yield, but I've gone through the logic many times and I don't get why it doesn't work.

Google and StackOverflow has recommended flatmaps, but I coulnd't get that to work either.

Any help would be appreciated. Keep in mind this is a class assignment with the skeleton methods set up, so I cannot change the way apply and groupFreq and charFreq are set up, I can only manipulate the bodies which I have tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error with some random text files of strings.  I suspect it occurred in an earlier iteration of `groupFreq()` w/o a `getOrElse()` type test.

However, when run your code, I end up with an empty map from the call to `charFreq()`.  You're correct that the loop/yield in charFreq() is problematic.  It's easier to see when you put a `val l =` in front of the `for` and check the value in an IDE which shoulds that `l` is of type `Iterator[Unit]`.

You don't need `vars` for the `for` loop.  The `for` loop isn't the same as a C-style for loop and is equivalent to calling flatMap/map over its elements ( though others can express this much better than I ).  The yield is being concatenated to something for you (defined by the steps you take inside it ).

Here are two ways to get an `Iterator[Char]` for your call to `groupFreq()`:

1> Remove the unnecessary `var it` and fill `chars` directly with a for comprehension loop:

```
val chars = for {
    xs<-words
    i<-xs.toIterator
} yield { i }
```

2> call `flatMap` directly on the `words` val:

```
val chars = words.flatMap( s => s )
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried your first solution and it worked. This was my very first assignment in Scala so it was difficult for me, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A. Regarding your problem, there is at least one issue I can spot in the code:

The way you build up an iterator (in charFreq) seems to be too heavy. `words.toIterator` would suffice.

The way you update the map also seems strange to me. I would rather do:

```
val mapped = f(x)
if (!(freqMap contains mapped) freqMap(mapped) = 0
freqMap(mapped)+=1
```

B. As far as I understand, this problem can be solved with a one-liner (which is why Scala is so cool of course ;-) )

```
def charFreq(file:String) = 
    file.toCharArray.groupBy(m=>m).map(m => (m._1,m._2.size))
```

Explanation:

1) `toCharArray` converts your string into an array of `Char` elements

2) groupBy(m=>m) groups together all elements with the same values, the result will be of type `Map[Char,Array[Char]]`, where every char is mapped to the array of all occurrences of that char in your string.

3) now all we need is to map each entry of the `Map[Char,Array[Char]]` to `Map[Char,Int]]` by using the mapping `map(m => (m._1,m._2.size))`, which takes every element (key->value), leaves the key intact and transforms the value (an array) into the size of that array.

4) If your input string is going to be very large (I haven't evaluated that but if it's in the ballpark of MB I'd start to worry about that), then I would probably use another solution, with mutable map which I'd fill up while iterating over the source:

```
def charFreq(hugeFile:String) = {
    //create a mutable map, which can be updated when needed
    val mm = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Char,Int]()
    //iterate over the string
    for (m <- hugeFile) { 
        //ensure that our map contains the entry for the given character
        if (! (mm contains m)) mm(m) = 0          
        mm(m) = mm(m)+1 
    }
    //return the result as an immutable map
    mm.toMap
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my code. as i said, first time coding in scala, so this helps me understand why scala was so awesome (instead of hating it because i was unfamiliar with it)